# Accessible TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, accessibility

I am trying to make my Android app more accessible as it is an important requirement these days. I am testing the app with Accessibility Scanner. But I am facing problems with TextInputLayouts. I have used the below code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_username"
    android:labelFor="@+id/username"
    android:contentDescription="@string/username_hint"
    android:accessibilityLiveRegion="polite">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

But Accessibility Scanner is terming TextInputLayout as unsupported item type. Also, id/username may not have a label readable by screen readers. Given below is the gradle as requested -

```
implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
```

Comment: Put your Edittext inside textinputlayout

Comment: It is inside only. I have mistakenly put the slash.

Comment: Can you show your gradle please.. i mean the dependencies

Comment: @UmangBurman  please find the gradle updated in the post.